# How to light up middle points in a display with 4 digits?

Tags: arduino-uno, display

How to light up the two points that is in the middle? It only lights up when the `digB` is set to `LOW`, and it lights up all 3 points that is in the middle.

[image: Item]

Example code:

```
const int displayPins[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
const int digA = 7;
const int digB = 4;
const int digC = 3;
const int digD = 8;
const int decimalPoint = 10;

void setup() {
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(displayPins)/sizeof(displayPins[0])); i++) {
        pinMode(displayPins[i], OUTPUT);
    }

    digitalWrite(digA, 1);
    digitalWrite(digB, 0);
    digitalWrite(decimalPoint, 1);
    digitalWrite(digC, 1);
    digitalWrite(digD, 1);
}

void loop() {
}
```

I want to display a clock in this format: 00:00. But did not found a way to light up the two points that is in the middle.

Comment: refer to the datasheet

Comment: @jsotola Did not found the right one, all that i found is the display with 4 digits and decimals without the two points in the middle. I also searched for the model of the item "sh5463AS-34", but did not found anything.

Comment: there are several schematics on the web ... the part number to search is in the picture you posted ... your question is not arduino specific ... voting to close

Comment: Try all the contacts that do not light up other segments. You will find the right ones eventually, if they can be separately controlled at all.

Comment: Possibly [this link about exactly the same question](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/controlling-4-digit-7-segment-display/227191) can help. This seems to suggest that what you want might not be possible if you have the same display.

Comment: The schematic on [this site](https://www.houkem.com.cn/5643-0-56-inch-seven-segment-led-clock-display-0-56-.html) shows,  that the three dots are all connected together, thus can only light up together. Seems to be the model, that you have. In that case you cannot do anything about that, other than buying a different 7segment display.

Comment: @chrisl the schematic diagram of the display may be incorrect ... the colon leds could actually be reversed

Comment: @jsotola What do you mean by "reversed"? The schematic shows the LEDs of the middle dots connected together on both sides. Or do you mean middle dots in one direction and the decimal dot in the other? We cannot really determine if the schematic is correct. That can only be done by testing the real component, but the schematic is consistent with the experiments of the OP so far

Comment: @chrisl i somehow missed the part about the three leds lighting ... have not had my morning coffee yet ... my thought was that reversing the polarity would light the colon leds ... looks like the display requires black tape for selecting the display mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to separate the colon dots from the decimal point dot - they are all wired together in parallel internally:

[image]

As has been mentioned in the comments you need to use the "black tape" method of selecting the LEDs. That's not a joke, that's really what's done. Cover the LED that you don't want visible with black tape (or black paint, etc).